# Excel - Perform a test on a precise character in a string

Tags: string, excel

For some reasons I have DNA sequences in Excel, typically long of 8 characters (ie: ATCACGTT).

I would like to perform a test (a IF function returning 1 if the letter is A/C, and O if the letter is G/T) on each of the characters of this string, consecutively.

The problem is that I can't find a function allowing me to precisely target one of the character of the string. For example the character in position 3 etc ...

Anyone have an idea please ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(OR(MID("$A$1",3,1)="A",MID("$A$1",3,1)="C"),1,0)
```

Will return a 1 if there is an A or a C in the 3rd position of cell A1

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not thought to use this function to target a single character.

Answer (score 0):

its macro not if function but it should work much better then if function that you want.

```
Sub Macro1()

Range("B6:B9").Select

Selection.Cells.Replace What:="C", Replacement:="1", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
  Selection.Cells.Replace What:="A", Replacement:="1", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
     Selection.Cells.Replace What:="G", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
  Selection.Cells.Replace What:="T", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

in range just write down the range of column in which you want to replace ACTG with 1 or 0. Remmember to insert in it your DNA sequences first

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VBA worksheet function that will convert DNA strings to binary strings, if that is what you're looking for.

```
Public Function DNAtoBinary(ByVal dna As String)

    'First check to make sure there are no invalid DNA characters
    Dim check As String
    check = UCase(dna)
    check = Replace(check, "A", vbNullString)
    check = Replace(check, "T", vbNullString)
    check = Replace(check, "G", vbNullString)
    check = Replace(check, "C", vbNullString)
    If Len(check) > 0 Then
        'Return #VALUE! if any characters left after removing A,C,G,&T
        DNAtoBinary = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Convert characters
    dna = UCase(dna)
    dna = Replace(dna, "A", "1")
    dna = Replace(dna, "C", "1")
    dna = Replace(dna, "G", "0")
    dna = Replace(dna, "T", "0")
    DNAtoBinary = dna

End Function
```